# How to get VTK's tuple size from vtkDataArray

Tags: c++, std, vtk

I'm trying to read all the data from all the tuples from a vtkDataArray class. However vtkDataArray::GetTuple as can be seen [here](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArray.html#ab82d1149eb4911c1bd28074fadb2d8db) returns a pointer to a double array. I'm wondering how can I get the size of that array. Seems like I'm missing an obvious solution.

Code snipet:

```
void doSomething(vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataArray> dataArray)
{
  vtkIdType numTuples = dataArray->GetNumberOfTuples();
  for (vtkIdType tupleIdx = 0; tupleIdx < numTuples; ++tupleIdx)
    {
        double* tuple = dataArray->GetTuple(tupleIdx);
        for (int j = 0; j < ¿¿¿???; ++j}
           double var = tuple[j];
           //Do something with var
           //Carefull don't go out of bounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `dataArray->GetNumberOfComponents()`. If you know the number of components then it may be easier to use other functions, for example, for 3 components you can use `dataArray->GetTuple3()`. VTK provides functions `GetTuple1()`, `GetTuple2()`, ... ,`GetTuple9()`.